# First derivative of a convex function, Disipative.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^d}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Let $<\cdot,\cdot>$ denote the usual Euclidean inner product. What can we say about 
$$ <x,\nabla f(x)>~~? $$

Is it true that $\exists$ $\eta,m >0$ such that for $|x|>m$

$$ <x,\nabla f(x)>\geq \eta |x|^2 $$

i.e there is some sort of dissipativity. What if $f$ was strictly convex?

Comment: This is not true, even for the strictly convex case. Consider $f(x) =e^x$ for example ($\langle x,\nabla f(x) \rangle = xe^x$, which is negative for all negative $x$). You should have a look at the notion of [coercive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function).

Comment: Strong convexity is also close to the thing you ask.

Comment: So does strong convexity assure this?